# Trouble accessing members of class from a separate class C++

Tags: c++

I am having a lot of trouble with a relatively simple task.  I have two header files, `input.h` and `grains.h`, both of which have classes defined within them. I have included all header and source files for this project below.

My problem is that when `input->from_file(fname)` is executed, the value printed to the screen is correct, let's say it is `4`.  Then when it moves on the `grains->get_pars()`, the value printed to the screen is garbage, usually `~605937280`.  I know this type of garbage value is indicative of the variable not being set, but I don't understand how it is not being set.

My goal is to have `input.cpp` read some file for some parameters, which are important to `grains.cpp`, and pass them along.  I thought that derived classes would do the trick, but something is not working right.  Any hints on what I have done wrong would be greatly appreciated.  Also, any suggestions to achieve this goal aside from the one I have presented are very welcome, thanks. Note, the code as shown compiles just fine.

```
//input.h
#ifndef Input_H
#define Input_H
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>

class Input {
  protected:
    int in_grains;
  public:
    void from_file(std::string);
};
#endif

//grains.h
#ifndef Grains_H
#define Grains_H
#include "input.h"

class Grains : protected Input {
  protected:
    int grains;
  public:
    void get_pars(void);
};
#endif


//input.cpp
#include "input.h"

void Input::from_file(std::string infile)
{ 
    std::ifstream input(infile.c_str());
    std::istringstream iss;
    std::string line, keyword;

    char arg1[50], arg2[50], arg3[50];

    while(std::getline(input,line)) {
        iss.clear();
        iss.str(line);
        iss >> keyword >> arg1 >> arg2 >> arg3;
        if ((keyword == "GRAINS") || (keyword == "Grains") || (keyword == "grains")) {
            this->in_grains = atoi(arg1);
        }
    }
    fprintf(stdout,"%i\n",in_grains );
}


//grains.cpp
#include "grains.h"

void Grains::get_pars(void)
{ 
    this->grains = in_grains;
    fprintf(stdout,"%i\n",grains );
}


//main.cpp
#include "input.h"
#include "grains.h"

int main(int nargs, char *argv[])
{ 
    Input obj1;
    Input *input = &obj1;

    Grains obj2;
    Grains *grains = &obj2;
    std::string fname = argv[1];

    input->from_file(fname.c_str());
    grains->get_pars();

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: You do not need `this->`

Comment: Why are you using `fprintf` for c++ code - not `cout`?

Comment: `std::string infile` - `const std::string &infile` would be better

Comment: Call `grains->from_file`, not `input->from_file` before `grains->get_pars`?

Comment: `in_grains` is not given a default value in the constructor of `Input`, so accessing it without setting it first will give an undefined value. Also, not sure what you are really trying to do with getting those pointers...

Comment: Ed: I know I dont need "this", but I wanted to make things more clear since this project is going to have a lot of classes with similar variable names.

Comment: It is bad practice and not necessary

Comment: You can save a lot of effort by using `std::transform` to covert `tolower` or `toupper`.  This means either comparing to `GRAINS` or `grains`. Otherwise you have ((2^7)-1) combinations to check in one `if` statement.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, didn't know that was an option!

Comment: Also, crashmstr.  When I set in_grains with the constructor, that is the value that grains->get_pars() sees for some reason, not the one provided by the input.  Thanks tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that when you execute:

```
input->from_file(fname.c_str());
grains->get_pars();
```

you are expecting the `in_grains` from `input` to be available as `grains->grains`. `input` and `grains` are two different objects. `in_grains` has not been set on the object `grains` points to.

Perhaps you meant to use:

```
int main(int nargs, char *argv[])
{ 
    Grains obj;
    Input *input = &obj;
    Grains *grains = &obj;
    std::string fname = argv[1];

    input->from_file(fname.c_str());
    grains->get_pars();

    return 0;    
}
```

However, to use that, you have to make `Input` a `public` base class of `Grain`, not a `protected` base class.

```
class Grains : public Input {
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this works great!  So from your code, if I understand it correctly, I messed up by having my class objects pointing to different addresses.  Is this the case?  I have been trying to teach myself C++, not sure how I missed that key point in the documents I have been reading.

Comment: @user3238310, that is correct. You had two objects not one.